# How to give path from one sub directory to other subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, path, directory

On root of application I have two folders:
1.Admin
2.JavaScript

My web page is in Admin folder and script file is in Javascript folder. How I should give path of script file in web page in Admin folder. I have tried these three ways but file is not found in brorser, please guide:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/Common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/Common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/JavaScript/Common.js"></script>
```

**Eidt**
In Admin folder I have master page and in same folder I have content page. The error I am getting on client side is showign javascript as it is in Admin panel like **"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:1532/MyProject/Admin/JavaScript/Common.js"**

Comment: second line should work, just check letters case, path is totally `case sensitive`

Comment: @Marek, is it really? I thought it depends on the web server and/or the server OS

Comment: no, it's universal to address parent directory like `../`

Comment: @user576510 from which URL are you requestiong file in JavaScript folder?

Comment: @user576510: are you using a ScriptManager?

Answer (score 1):

Leading slash replaces the entire pathname of the base URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript/Common.js"></script>
```

By your edit, your project is no off the root as you suggested.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyProject/JavaScript/Common.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need some more help plz. Kindly see my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example looks correct, so you should check the case of the directories.  Personally I like the following method, which would work in any of your files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript/Common.js"></script>
```

`/` at the beginning of a string specifies the root, which is what it looks like you want.

**Edit**
From your update, it looks like you want
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyProject/JavaScript/Common.js"></script>`.

The root (`/`) specifies the slash **right** after the port.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative path like you have in your second example, or you can use a direct path from the root:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JavaScript/Common.js"></script>
```

Just make sure your path is accessible and that you've haven't typoed any of the directory names, etc. That's usually my problem when I have a file that's not loading properly.

Comment: I need some more help plz. Kindly see my Edit.

Comment: Did you try to use `/JavaScript/Common.js` as the `src`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JavaScript/Common.js")%>"></script>
```

The tilde(~) is the ASP.NET way to go to the root-directory. This works on server controls and with [ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx).

If you are using a ScriptManager in your MasterPage do following:

Add the path to your javascript file(s) as [ScriptReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference.aspx) to your `ScriptManager/ToolkitScriptManager`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
       <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/Common.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

More informations: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2004/05/05/avoiding-problems-with-relative-and-absolute-urls-in-asp-net.aspx